# Why to depend on shadow jar?

Tags: gradle, gradle-shadow-plugin

I've been reading gradle shadow plugin documentation and found that it allows one project to depend on shadowed jar of another project

```groovy
dependencies {
  compile project(path: 'api', configuration: 'shadow')
}
```

I'm now curious what are use cases for this functionality?